# how does this work in ARC

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, automatic-ref-counting

```
-(void)add
{
    Myview *optionV =[[Myview alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80,80, 590, 25)];
    [interactiveView addSubview:optionV];

   //interactiveView is UIView added from the nib and has an IBoutlet.
}
```

now if add method is being called 10 times. How is the memory being managed. what is the best way with out creating @property for Myview.

Comment: all fine with this code under ARC

Comment: each time when add method is called new  objects of Myview  are created and added to interactiveView ? what will happen to previous objects. will interactiveView retain them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ARC adds a simple release at compile time, so your code will be rewritten in this way:

```
-(void)add
{
    Myview *optionV =[[Myview alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80,80, 590, 25)];
    [interactiveView addSubview:optionV];
    [optionV release]; //Will be added when compiled, Don't add it your self.
}
```

Comment: Just to make things 100% clear, it's important to remember that a view `retain`s its subviews, and `release`s them when they're removed.

Comment: @Jasarien: possibly that's better phrased as that it's interactiveView's responsibility to retain optionV if it wants to? The general principle is that each class is responsible for its own memory management; the specific fact that UIViews retain subviews isn't something that the ARC compiler is aware of.